# Is there some way I can adjust the aspect ratio of video output without changing the resolution?

Tags: windows-10, display

I have a windows 10 NUC class machine (with the 'older' intel tools, and a N300 processor with intel HD graphics 400 video) that's hooked up to an old plasma TV. I'm using a HDMI connection to a generic/off brand active HDMI to VGA adaptor (I had a native VGA connection in the past with similar issues) . In the TV is 16:9 and supports 1024x768 and 800x600 inputs, but practically 800x600 is the resolution that works - it does some kinda scaling and stretches it.

The output on the TV is somewhat squashed 'vertically' as a result

I've looked around the TV controls, and though there's a 4:3 correction option, its disabled, and that's out of the scope of this, or any SE site, and I can't seem to find any other options that'll work

Is there some way I can 'correct' for this in windows and output an already scaled image so it'll look undistorted - essentially I want to 'squash' the output of the system horizontally for 'real' 4:3 or "emulate" a 16:9 screen, appropriately squashed so the TV's widescreen setup fixes it

Answer (score 0):

*My first idea for this was going to crop rather than squeeze. I'll leave it below for any future users who may need a permanent crop setting.

The first part of this answer now sets a 'squeeze' instead.*

---

What you need is to 'squeeze' a 16:9 image so the TV will then re-expand it onto a stretched 16:9 generated from a 4:3 input.
Confused? I certainly was ;)
I can't actually test this, but it seems to work in theory.

VLC can be set to force an aspect ratio, no matter what the actual picture ratio is. This is deep inside the Advanced prefs. It's designed to correct for a badly-described DVD image, but it works just as well to override a correctly-described image.

[image]

Here is the resulting squeeze inside a 16:9 frame. This should properly re-expand to fit 800x600 on a 16:9 screen

[image]

---

*Below is the original crop idea, just in case it's useful to anyone else in future. It also gives comparative images so you can see how the different method actually look.*

---

VLC can Crop to 4:3 output from a 16:9 source.
It will by default, in fullscreen, expand or contract to fill the available screen area, even if the aspect ratios match.

There is an option deep in the prefs to set a custom crop such as 4:3 as a default, but I can't test how it would display on a 4:3 screen.

[image]

On a 16:9 display I get black pillarbox bars. This is, of course, a hard crop - you are going to lose the edges of the source video.
Example showing a 2.35:1 input then cropped to 4:3 output - but both displayed in a 16:9 frame.
As far as I can determine, the black bars are not considered to be part of the picture & will not be shown once the aspect ratios do match.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh, its a little messier than that. I kinda want to 'squash' the former to the latter aspect ratio, as opposed to crop, if that makes sense. . Also, is that intergalactic? :D

Comment: I just realised that - I added an oops to the answer… & going for a rethink. Is is indeed Intergalactic. I just still had it kicking around on this machine - it will be going in the bin as soon as we've ironed this issue out. It was absolute pants. Didn't get through episode 2 ;)

Comment: OK, think I've got it - updating answer...

Comment: Ah - for extra fun, The show I'm watching now is in 4:3 aspect ratio so its effectively stretching it - hence the desire to 'fix' the output globally. I vaguely recall a way to do this in xrandr, but I had a different fun problem in linux so...

Comment: Being able to correct for both 16:9 AND 4:3 is going to need some automatic recognition mode - which is usually in the purview of the TV rather than the source image. You can force the aspect ratio on the fly from VLC, in the regular Video menu, but I see no way to define two defaults.